# Setting product SKU

Tags: ubercart, views

I'm trying to change 600 products so that the node SKU is set to the value of the node's title. I want to use VBO to accomplish this, with the "execute arbitrary PHP script" option. Here is the code I am using:

```
$new_node = node_load($object->nid);
$new_node->model = $object->title;
node_save($new_node);
```

However, this does not work. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: i believe you need to prepare the node for editing. see if `node_object_prepare($new_node);` will help you out. [node_object_prepare](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_object_prepare/7)

Comment: did u use std class?

Comment: I ended up using uc_product_power_tools and then looping through my products with a php script to update. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get it to work was to do this:

```
$node->model = $sku;
node_save($node);
```

The reason I could not get values was because of revisions. I changed function "uc_product_get_models". Line 1357 changed to:

```
 $models[] = db_query('SELECT model FROM {uc_products} WHERE nid = :nid order by vid desc', array(':nid' => $nid))->fetchField();
```

I know changing core is bad, but:

- It seems to be fixed in the dev version
- I have no idea when the dev version is going to be released again, but when it does, the change will already be there.